# Show d.e. has infinite sequence of zeros - Find upper and lower bounds within limit.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that every solution of the d.e.

$$y''+(3-\cos x)y=0$$
has an infinite sequence of zeros. Find the upper and lower bounds for number of zeros in
$$0\leq x\leq 2\pi$$$$ a(x)=3-\cos x$$$$a(x)\geq 3-1=2$$$$v''+2v=0$$$$v=\cos \sqrt{2}x$$$$x_i=i\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$$$(i\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}},(i+1)\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}),   i=0,1,2..........$$$$x_1-x_0$$$$3-\cos x\leq 3-(-1)=4$$$$M=\sqrt{4}=2$$$$x_1-x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

> But where to from here?